# POST request to Flask Blueprint api not working

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I am trying to execute a form POST request. The request is received at the route api function but the POST condition is not executing.

**Code**

```
<form class="pt-2 pb-4" action = "{{ url_for('data_sources_api.testfn') }}" method = "POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="url" class="form-label">URL</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" name="url" aria-describedby="emailHeurllp"
                placeholder="Enter new events top domain source url">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Organization Name">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2" value="submit" name = "submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Flask Code**

```
@data_sources_api.route('/login/test', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def testfn():
    # Check if user is loggedin
    if loggedin():
        # User is loggedin, render the home page
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("POST Request Received")
            result = request.form
        return render_template('users/data-sources.html', role=session['role'])
    return redirect(url_for('account_api.login'))
```

The request received is GET when i click the submit button and not POST :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with button. Replace the button with input type="submit":

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/) is the example of Django form.